# css apply from one tab to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, tabs

i want is that when i click on the profile tab i get the green color css(class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled") enabled over profile and disable over home tab button/ how can i do this?

```
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li><a href="#home" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled" data-toggle="tab" >Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Write Here Tab Home Part</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Write Here Tab Profile Part</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Write Here Tab Messages Part</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Write Here Tab Settings Part</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You forgot your important tag... jQuery or javascript :)

Comment: Or some framework like Angular :)

Comment: i am using Bootstrap tabs. i want a javascript that can change the green color from home tab to profile tab or whatever tab i click on. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li").click(
 function(){
  $("[class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled']").removeClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
  $(this).children("a").addClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using css, so I'll use jQuery in this case:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('btn-success').siblings('a').removeClass('btn-success');
}
```